# Azure EventHub consumer group with mutiple readers

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I've an Azure EventHub EH1 set up with a ConsumerGroup CG1. I also have an app A1 that uses  CG1 to read from EH1.

For the sake of resiliency, I have another *independent* copy of the same app A2 deployed in a different region and it also needs to read from EH1.

In short A1 and A2 need to be able to *exclusively and independently* read and process all of the data from EH1.

With this in mind -

- Can A2 also be set up to use CG1 to read from EH1. Looking at
  [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#consumer-groups) it seems that it would work - just want to make sure I'm
  reading it right.
- If the above works, how would it be different
  from having A2 set up to connect to EH1 with a new consumer group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not recommended to share consumer groups across different apps. You should create a new consumer group for your app 'A2' so, that 'A1' and 'A2' can run totally independent of each other.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.
A2 and A1 are 2 different instances of the same app, they are independent in every way though.